# Trouble with 応じる

Tags: verbs, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes に基づいて instead of に応じて the correct choice for this question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/what-makes-%e3%81%ab%e5%9f%ba%e3%81%a5%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-instead-of-%e3%81%ab%e5%bf%9c%e3%81%98%e3%81%a6-the-correct-choice-for-this-question)

I am having trouble with the following sentence.

情報はシナリオの進行に応じて追加されていきますので、時折覗いてみると良いでしょう。

I think it says something along the lines of, "The information adds to the development of the scenario, but if you try looking ahead from time to time that is okay.", but I'm not completely sure. Could someone explain the use of 応じる?

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/what-makes-%E3%81%AB%E5%9F%BA%E3%81%A5%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-the-correct-choice-for-this-question

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what they're talking about without context, but I would at least translate it as something closer to "Information will be added based on the progress of the scenario, so it might be good to take a look from time to time."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

に応じる usually means in relation to what ever is happening before the phase.

For example:

- 必要に応じて　would be "As necessary"
- XYZの進行に応じて would be along the line　of "as XYZ progresses"
- XYZの結果に応じて would be "according to the consequences of"

(I'll add more if question becomes popular)