# What's the difference between によって、次第、and 応じて?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Can someone please help me understand What is the difference between によって、次第、and 応じて.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30918/7810

Comment: Another related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6102/7810

Comment: I'd like to just put my comment. Add the sentences related your question. Or I don't understand what are you seeking.

Answer (score 2):

によって　is spoken.

次第 is written very formal. I almost never get to use this when it's meaning is +- that of によって but i use it all the time to describe a sequence (in sequence, in order, in turn) particularly when I'm explaining CPUs to customers.

応じて written, not as formal. As well as 'depends on/depending on' it can also mean in proportion to. so 「天気によって・・・」and 「天気に応じて・・・」are kinda like "depends on the weather" and "weather appropriate"